# @Scheduled tasks failing to execute

Tags: windows, grails, scheduled-tasks

I have grails 4.0.2 running on Windows 7. Following the most basic section of the @Scheduled guide found here:

https://guides.grails.org/grails-scheduled/guide/index.html

I'm not receiving any output to console. I even attempted to use their provided project. Here is the relevant code:

In grails-app/conf/logback.groovy

```
logger('demo', INFO, ['STDOUT'], false)
```

In grails-app/services/demo/HelloWorldJobService.groovy

```
package demo

import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

@Slf4j 
@CompileStatic 
class HelloWorldJobService {

    static lazyInit = false 

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000L) 
    void executeEveryTen() {
        log.info "Simple Job every 10 seconds :{}", new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss").format(new Date())
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 45000L, initialDelay = 5000L) 
    void executeEveryFourtyFive() {
        log.info "Simple Job every 45 seconds :{}", new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss").format(new Date())
    }
}
```

Since this is intended to be a simple guide, I'm assuming there's a configuration error on my end, but I haven't been able to find it yet.

Comment: Have you enabled scheduling per the guide in section 3.4 Task Scheduler Bean? If you clone the guide does it work?

Comment: When I follow the guide up to 3.2, it states that it should have two simple scheduled tasks, so I haven't gotten that far yet. If I use the completed version they provide, it only seems to execute the one in 3.7.

Comment: Then I believe the guide is incorrect - spring-scheduling will not work without @EnableScheduling on the app or a scheduler configured - https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/#_enable_scheduling

Comment: That link immediately solved my problem. Please post an answer so I can mark it as the solution.

Comment: Great, it may be worth opening an issue on the github repo for that guide so they can address the issue.

Comment: @erichelgeson I think it was addressed earlier today with https://github.com/grails-guides/grails-scheduled/commit/3b48c4b7959ce1373ef1f8c921d530362b7689ab.  If that is all good then no need for opening an issue at this point.  Thanks for all of the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the guide is incorrect - spring-scheduling will not work without `@EnableScheduling` on the app or a scheduler configured -

https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/#_enable_scheduling

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. I am fixed the guide live. What eric pointed out was the issue.

In addition, i found we have this in our docs buried. Thanks

https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/upgrading.html

Scheduled Methods

```
In Grails 3 no configuration or additional changes were necessary to use the Spring @Scheduled annotation. In Grails 4 you must apply the @EnableScheduling annotation to your application class in order for scheduling to work.
```